# Prevent stop of code execution on undefined value

Tags: javascript

Often, I write something like this:

```
if(model.properties.foo.bar){
    // ...
} 

else{
   // ...
}
```

Currently, I want to fetch a document only if it isn't already cached. To do so, I write an if-statement like above, checking for the title of the current document.

However, if there is no current document because the user just entered my application, this check will fail due to an undefined `model.properties`. An error is thrown and the `else` block won't execute.

What is the commonly best practive to write such checks?

Comment: Can you test if `model` is defined first?

Comment: `if (model && 'properties' in model && 'foo' in model.properties && 'bar' in model.properties.foo && model.properties.foo.bar)`

Comment: Sure. I am looking for the cleanest possible way to do this, though, with the least possible effort

Answer (score 0):

```
if(model.properties != null){

      if (model.properties.foo.bar) {
         // ...
      } else {
         // ...
      }
    // ...
} 

else{
   // ...
}
```

Comment: This will fail if `model` is not defined.